# Need to make a 4 position switch using one button input and SMD IC's

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, surface-mount

I have a system that can only have one push button input and I positions      . I'm limited on space and power, however I will gladly yield some power to save space.

I'm trying to find integrated circuit packages that can take a single input and drive one of four outputs. I'm new to the electrical field and after a few days of searching through digikey and reading datasheets, I'm not finding what I need.

NOTE: NO MICROCONTROLLERS please. Seriously, let's not be lazy.

I can typically find this on my own, but this time I can't seem to find the right IC.

Comment: Please reword to make it clear that you are asking a design question (on topic) vs a shopping question (off topic). Does your board have any clocks available? What voltages are available? Also, why not a microprocessor?

Comment: Who are you calling lazy?

Comment: I thought micro's were more work.

Comment: Micros are less up-front work, just more expensive.

Comment: Good call - MCUs bring a pile of costs associated with software release/control and programming/testing during manufacturing, which some users on here seem to skip past.

Answer (score 1):

A 4017 style counter should do the job. You will also need a circuit to debounce your mechanical switch. A 555 timer is often a good choice for this

Comment: you would need at least one more chip. A counter by itself does not toggle one at a time through 4 different outputs. Possibly a shift register could work.

Comment: Then you should read a 4017 datasheet. It has a clock input with 10 decoded outputs. You can reset at a lower count by routing an output to the reset input.

Comment: So it does. Cool. So it is a single-chip solution. If the debounce can be addressed somehow.

Comment: The debounce is handled by the 555 I suggested. The part cost is so low, it is hard to beat.

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot of hair from being pulled out, time to read up and get building!

Comment: @DRKMSTR, perhaps you would consider accepting this answer if it helped you. Or making a suggestion for how it could be modified to be acceptable.